# How to make an object list from XML with Java Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

I want to get data from an [API](https://www.lb.lt/webservices/FxRates/FxRates.asmx?op=getCurrentFxRates) it gives me XML data like [this](https://www.lb.lt/webservices/FxRates/FxRates.asmx/getCurrentFxRates?tp=eu)

I can map the last of these to an object. See the code bellow:

```
public void getCurrencies() {

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        Currency currency = null;
        try {
            currency = xmlMapper.readValue(
                    new URL("https://www.lb.lt/webservices/FxRates/FxRates.asmx/getCurrentFxRates?tp=eu"),
                    Currency.class);
            CurrencyBase c = currency.getCurrencyBase();
            CurrencyAmount d = c.getCurrencyAmount();
            System.out.println(d.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

But how do I parse the XML data to a list of objects?

My model for the currency:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "FxRates")
public class Currency {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "FxRate")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true)
    private CurrencyBase currencyBase;


public class CurrencyBase {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Tp")
    private String type;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dt")
    private String date;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CcyAmt")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true)
    private CurrencyAmount currencyAmount;

public class CurrencyAmount {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Ccy")
    private String Name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Amt")
    private String ConvertionRate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use TypeReference to map the List of Objects. You have list of CurrencyBase rather than Currency itself. Here is the code changes to make it work:

```
    public void getCurrencies() {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    List<CurrencyBase> currency = null;
    try {
        currency = xmlMapper.readValue(
                new URL("https://www.lb.lt/webservices/FxRates/FxRates.asmx/getCurrentFxRates?tp=eu"),
                new TypeReference<List<CurrencyBase>>(){});
        System.out.println(currency);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Also have to change @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false) and change CurrencyAmount to List :

```
public class CurrencyBase {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Tp")
    private String type;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Dt")
    private String date;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CcyAmt")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<CurrencyAmount> currencyAmount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. What did you mean by "change @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true)"? My code and your suggestion are identical.

Comment: Welcome. I posted wrong for the part @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true)"...I have updated it to map to List of CurrencyAmount